# SQL Server: How to write a query to select id having all values less than 0(zero)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table,

Table 1:

```
id (int):         1   1   2   2   2
value (int):     -1   0  -1  -3  -8
```

How to write a query to select the `id` from the table which has all the values of column value less than 0?

Comment: You should make an attempt.

Comment: I couldnt find a way to do it. I need some help with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    id INT,
    value INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp (id, value) 
VALUES (1, -1), (1, 0), (2, -1), (2, -3), (2, -8)

SELECT id 
FROM @temp
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(value) < 0
```

Output -

```
id
-----------
2
```

Comment: Say you normalised it as well, that's cheating! :)

Comment: @MitchWheat.. amateur becomes an expert when he learns. There is nothing wrong in being amateur nor an amateur wanting to learn.